# how to rid "" from a string to non string

Tags: python

I have this

```
a = "'Something': False"
```

I want it to be this

```
a = 'Something': False
```

How do I do it? I can strip things within the double quotation marks, but not the quotation marks itself. Have researched, cant find. I have mind block at moment. Sorry

Im trying to do this:

```
query_results = UserProfile.objects.filter(Location: location, Gender: gender).extra(select={'rank': a > 0}, order_by=['-rank'])
```

where Location = Someplace and Gender = Male or Female.

But what about when i did not want a specific gender or location. The only thing i could think of to do  was to do

```
Location__isnull:False,  Gender__isnull:False
```

But i cant have both

```
Location:location, Location__isnull:False.
```

Thus i have to have the location argument as a variable.

How could i then do this. The information referring to Location and gender is coming from a request.GET

I cant post my code as i keep deleting and changing spaghetti to try make something edible.

Comment: Your second example is invalid syntax. Did you mean `a = { 'Something': False }`?

Comment: thats the problem see. I want to put 'a' in {}. As in {a}

Comment: What are you gonna do with `a`? If you print it out, the result is already `'Something': False`.

Comment: `a = 'Something': False` is a `SyntaxError`. Did you mean `a = {'Something': False}` perhaps?

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve?  it seems like you might have wandered into the weeds.  Maybe you should show us a bit more code.

Comment: If you don't want to filter, then *don't filter*!! Just omit the `.filter()` part!

Comment: @JT: Sorry, but this needs more context. What ORM is this? Why can't you have both of those? Why not just omit Location if you have no value for it? What does this have to do with strings?

Comment: Sometimes i will want to filter and sometimes i wont. I want it to be variable with out hard coding the changes.

Comment: its django and mysql. I cant have both because it will always read the Location: location over Location__isnull: False

Comment: its django and mysql. I cant have both because it will always read the Location: location over Location__isnull: False. Thus i want the location argument to be variable. lets say .filter(loca1) where loca1= (Location: location) or Loca1=(Location__isnull:False)

Comment: See my answer. I think you are struggling for this syntax: `function(**dictwithkwargs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're trying to do, the easiest way is to build up a dictionary of the arguments you want to supply, then pass them to the filter() call. Here's some non-working sample code that might get you heading in the right direction.

```
arguments = {}
if location is not None:
    arguments['Location'] = location
else:
    arguments['Location__isnull'] = False

if gender is not None:
    arguments['Gender'] = gender
else:
    arguments['Gender__isnull'] = False

query_results = UserProfile.objects.filter(**arguments)
```

It's not clear from your question whether or not you really need to search these for records which are not null. An empty `.filter()` would return all the records just as if you'd called `.all()`, and if you use the pattern I've suggested, you could omit all the else clauses and  just feed `filter(**arguments)` an empty dictionary.

In other words, you only need to specify the query terms you really require, and do that by adding them to the arguments dictionary. Then you call filter with `**arguments`. The `**` is a special Python syntax that says "take all the key/value pairs in this dictionary and turn them into keyword arguments for this function."

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is *not* valid python syntax: `'Something': False` ... unless it's inside a dictionary: `{'Something': False}`. And no, you can not assign `'Something': False` to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
stufftofilter = {}
if shouldFilterLocation:
    stufftofilter['Location'] = 'thelocation'
# etc
query_set = UserProfile.objects.extra(select={'rank':a>0}, order_by=['-rank'])
if stufftofilter:
    query_set.filter(**stufftofilter)
```